# i want to convert images(3~4ea) and mp3 to mp4 file

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg

i am convert images(3~4) and mp3 to video with ffmpeg

i use this command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i %05d.jpg -i sample.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

converting is well done. but, Images are changing very short period.

i want to set images changing period once every 10~15 seconds.

How would I do that using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no need to use `loop` for this task. you can simply specify `framerate` instead which will control the time duration according to your request. Following will work for you with 10 sec duration between each image.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/10 -i screenshot%06d.jpg -i track2.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

Read the [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) for more information.